# Sequential Circuit Analysis

Tags: logic

[image]

In the question above can someone explain to me what Da and Db represent. Do Da and Db input equations represent the next state in the flip flop Q(t+1) when the clock has a rising edge?

Answer (score 0):

Da and Db represent the states of the actual flip flops.

so the equations determine when those states are high or low.
A and B are the outputs from the flip flops.

usually you don't have to worry about clock inputs in this sort of problem.

To be honest this question is a little vague... but by all convention i'm aware of i think i'm correct.